# No image required CodeIgniter 3. How?

Tags: php, validation, file-upload, codeigniter-3

I have a problem verifying whether the image was selected or not. I use CodeIgniter 3 and I have no idea how to do it. I have this code:

```
if ($this->input->post('adminImage') == null){
    $data['image'] = base_url('assets/images/default_avatar.png');
} else {
    $config['upload_path'] = './assets/images/admins';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
    $config['max_size'] = 10240;
    $config['max_width'] = 512;
    $config['max_height'] = 512;
    $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ($this->upload->do_upload('adminImage')) {
        $uploadData = $this->upload->data();
        $data['image'] = base_url('assets/images/admins/' . $uploadData['file_name']);
    } else {
        $_SESSION['messageDangerSm'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
        redirect(base_url('panel/admins'));
    }
}
```

If I do not choose an image, it works, sends to the database a previously defined link with the image. But the problem is that even if I choose a picture, it still sends a link to the database with the default picture and not selected by the user. How to fix it so that after selecting the image it sends to the database a link with the image, and if you do not choose this default image? Thank you in advance for your help :)

And sorry for my English xD

Comment: not enough information provided. If the standard Image is always set i guess  $this->input->post('adminImage') is always == null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where is the part of your code that is sending to your db?

```
 if (!empty($_FILES['file']['name'])) {

    $config['upload_path'] = './assets/images/admins';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
    $config['max_size'] = 10240;
    $config['max_width'] = 512;
    $config['max_height'] = 512;
    $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ($this->upload->do_upload('file')) {
    $uploadData = $this->upload->data(file_name);

    // now you need to send this to your model and upload to you db
    }
    else {
        $_SESSION['messageDangerSm'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
        redirect(base_url('panel/admins'));
    }
```